# How can I get Java / Spring MVC to return jsonapi.org ID based format?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, ember.js, ember-data

I am implementing a JSON API to be used by the Ember-Data REST Adapter.

The Ember-Data REST Adapter needs the JSON returned to follow this format:

http://jsonapi.org/format/

Ember-Data documentation:

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-conventions

I know how to return JSON, say, using Spring MVC 3.2 / Jackson, that's not a problem. However, the JSON format must adhere to the format specified at jsonapi.org.

You can find a sample Django implementation if you google "ember data tastypie adapter" (sorry, not enough reputation points for a link [sic]), and rable also seems to have one.

Seems like jsonapi.org is a much referred to standard for several frameworks / languages.

Do I really need to implement this standard in Java myself?

Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: You will probably need to implement a custom Jackson serializer.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the only solution. I can't really find anything on a Java implementation. Seems like the new Spring MVC 3.2 HyperMedia format uses the Hypertext Application Language (HAL) [http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html], but this format seems to have been rejected by the jsonapi.org format [http://jsonapi.org/faq/]. If I get the time to write such a serialiser, I'll make sure to open source it....

Comment: Serialiser + parser, actually :-) Needs complete CRUD operation set. Bummer. I think I'll have to put Ember Data on my nice-to-have list for now.

Answer (score 2):

There are some JSON:API implementations for Java:

- [Katharsis](https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-framework) with Spring support but somehow **dead** for years
- [Crnk](https://github.com/crnk-project/crnk-framework) with Spring Boot 2 support is **much more** than just JSON:API serializer/deserializer
- [JSON:API for Spring HATEOAS](https://github.com/toedter/spring-hateoas-jsonapi) based on Spring HATEOAS and Jackson with Boot 2 support, very **lightweight but fresh**

To clarify I have not used any of the libraries but if I have to I would try the last one from Kai Toedter unless I have the need for a very large system with JSON:API only so I can benefit from all the additional magic.

Answer (score 0):

Genson appears to support JSONAPI format.

This is an example unit test:

[JsonSerDeserSymetricTest.java](https://code.google.com/p/genson/source/browse/src/test/java/com/owlike/genson/JsonSerDeserSymetricTest.java?r=2b80106be551560dd27cef4197de0d0500e93439)

demonstrating deserialising a feed into classes.  The classes include:

[Feed.java](https://code.google.com/p/genson/source/browse/src/test/java/com/owlike/genson/bean/Feed.java?r=2b80106be551560dd27cef4197de0d0500e93439) - which has an id field
[Link.java](https://code.google.com/p/genson/source/browse/src/test/java/com/owlike/genson/bean/Link.java?r=2b80106be551560dd27cef4197de0d0500e93439) - which has a href field

Genson will integrate with [Spring MVC](https://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/SpringIntegration) and [Jersey for JAX-RS](https://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/JerseyIntegration).

Comment: There is nothing in Genson or in that class that resembles the jsonapi spec.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can change the JSON property inside spring config file like this:

```
<bean
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
<property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

You can take a look at [Spring JSON Mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html#setPrefixJson%28boolean%29) also.

I hope this helped out !